# high trust provider hosted app on premises asking credentials again

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

My environment is:

1. Sharepoint server with Provider hosted app hosted in same server as sharepoint.
2. High Trust issuer and all High Trust App requirements (certificates, etc) are set up as per:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901.aspx

The app is called MyApp and is found in Dev site.
The user is already logged in sharepoint, and clicks MyApp. The issue we are facing is that when the user is not in the domain, the provider hosted app will ask for credentials again.

We are using this app for an extranet site, the user will log in, but we don't want them enter the credentials again.

Is this the correct behavior? Is there any way the user can enter to the provider hosted app without entering the credentials again (and not set the domain in the internet options). We also are not using ADFS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which authentication you are using for Sharepoint site and for your iis site containing provider hosted app ?

Comment: As per Guide in configuring High Trust apps, the IIS website is Windows Authentication. Sharepoint is a custom FDA. However, I can change it.. i just need the external user to log once and not again when accessing the provider hosted app.

Comment: Hello nerlijma, Were you able to resove the above issue. If yes, you can help us as we are getting the same.

Comment: Hi Kunal, sadly, we quit using provider hosted appa for extranet as we could not make it to work for an extranet environment. We ended using sharepoint only as CMS for extranet and the app logic with a regular asp.net application with same styles (so the end user won't notice the difference)